# How to reference an XML element nested within an unknown amount of other elements

Tags: c#, xml

I want to reference an XML element that is nested within an unknown amount of other elements. 
For example, if I have an XML file like this:

```
<root>
    <Example>
    </Example>
</root>
```

And I want to add an element within the `<Example>` element. When I add an element within the root element I can do it like this (assuming `Doc` is an already defined XDocument):

```
Doc.Element("root").Add(new XElement("Example"));
```

And if there are two, I can do:

```
Doc.Element("root").Element("Example").Add(new XElement("newExample"))
```

This works fine if I know exactly what elements are going to be within what, because I can hard code it. This does not work, however, when I don't know what elements are going to be in what.

My project is a virtual folder system (makes more sense if you read [this](https://github.com/CobaltsDev/Virtual-Folder-System/wiki)), so I don't know what elements will be nested within what. I have thought of saving the directory within the program in a `List<string>`, which works to store the directory, but because the only way I know how to reference elements is with hard coding every single element. Is there a way I can reference any element nested within any other element without having to hard code every parent element so I can use methods like XElement.Add()?

Comment: Answer by SLaks (`Descendants`) answers the question *as asked*. Stating that it does not without any explanation why it does not work is very confusing (but quite traditional - it is common to see comments from OP as "no, even if I asked for it I need something different"... but it does not make such comments useful).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov he says that the Descendants method works, alright that's great! I cannot use that knowledge if I have no idea how to implement it or use it. AKA A nearly useless piece of information.

Comment: There we go, I edited it so that I specify that the reference has to _do_ something. I was assuming that people could tell that I need the reference to be used in something like the XElement.Add() method because the entire rest of the question was using examples saying what I know I can do to make the XElement.Add() and other likewise methods work, and why what I am currently doing does not satisfy what I need for more dynamic functionality.

Comment: You need to add to the parent of the tag. You can use : XElement parentExample = doc.Descendants("ParentExample").FirstOrDefault();  Then : parentExample.Add(new XElement("Example", 123456));

Comment: @jdweng Thank you so much for that, it works like a charm. Could you make an answer for that so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: What always confuses people is Descents returns a list object so you need to use FirstOrDefault() to get a singular.  You can't use Add() to an array or list object.

Comment: May I ask what this is being downvoted for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the `Descendants()` method, which returns exactly that.

If you want to get a specific element with a specific path, just write a loop:

```
var el = root;
foreach (var name in path)
    el = el.Element(name);
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? How would I use that to add things to an element?

Comment: @Sharp_: That depends on how you want to pick which element to add to.  Depending on what you actually want, you want either this or a loop.

Comment: If I were to use XElement.Add to add to my preferred element, could I do something like Doc.Descendants("Example").Add(new XElement("newExample"))?

Comment: @Sharp_: Yes, but that will add to _every_ `<Example>` element in the document, which may not be what you want.

Comment: So does your answer actually answer my original question? That being 'is there any way I could reference an element nested within other elements without having to hardcode the entire thing?'

Comment: @Sharp_: Yes, but it completely depends on _how you want to pick that element_.

Comment: I currently pick the element like this `Doc.Element("root").Element("Example").Add(new XElement("newExample"))` I am asking if I can reference an element without having to hardcode the entire tree because I _cannot_ know how long the tree is before I run the program. I also already know the name of every element that the one I'm trying to pick is nested under, what I want to know is how to implement that into something like `XElement.Add();` without having to hardcode it.

Comment: So after trying to test this, that does not work. the 'var' you use for 'el' would have to be an XDocument if `el.Element(name);` were to work. This is fine except you can't make el equal to that statement because it returns an XElement, not an XDocument.

Comment: @Sharp_: So declare it as `XElement`.  You don't need to use `var`,

Comment: @SLacks you don't get that to use el.Element() el must be an XDocument. You cannot set el to el.Element() because el returns an XElement

Comment: @Sharp_: Wrong; `XElement` also has an `Element()` method.

Comment: Well that helps to know, I figured out how to use to Descendants() method with the help of @jdweng. I will do a solve my own question and credit him and you for helping me find the answer.

Comment: FYI: this is now being [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352217/question-ban-currently-seems-inescapable-for-me).